# Как совместить нечеткий поиск с инкрементным?

Tags: java, поиск, полнотекстовый-поиск, lucene, нечеткий-поиск

Мой код, получая на вход запрос, должен обеспечить для каждого слова нечеткий(fuzzy) поиск, а для последнего слова - еще и инкрементный.

```
private static final Pattern QUERY_SPLIT_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\s+");
Query luceneQuery = queryParser.parse(QUERY_SPLIT_PATTERN.splitAsStream(query).collect(Collectors.joining("~" + maxEdits + " +", "+", "~" + maxEdits + "*")));
```

Проблема в том, что для последнего слова я могу либо добавить `*` в качестве суффикса, и поиск будет инкрементный, либо `~1`, тогда будет нечеткий поиск в дистанцией в 1. Если же в качестве суффикса последнего слова я пытаюсь вставить `~1*`, то я получаю следующую ошибку

```
org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.ParseException: '*' or '?' not allowed as first character in WildcardQuery
```

Как мне обойти это?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте создать два условия поиска последнего слова. В объектном виде будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
BooleanQuery topLevelQuery = new BooleanQuery();
//строим условие по последнему слову
BooleanQuery booleanQuery = new BooleanQuery();
WildcardQuery wildcardQuery = new WildcardQuery(new Term(fieldName, fieldValue));
booleanQuery.add(wildcardQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
FuzzyQuery fuzzyQuery = new FuzzyQuery(new Term(fieldName, fieldValue), LevenshteinAutomata.MAXIMUM_SUPPORTED_DISTANCE);
booleanQuery.add(fuzzyQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
topLevelQuery.add(booleanQuery);
//строим условия по остальным словам и добавляем - topLevelQuery.add(otherWordQuery)
```

Для настройки весов разных частей условия можно использовать метод `setBoost()`. Это может пригодиться, например, для того, чтобы точные совпадения в `wildcardQuery` поднимались выше неточных совпадений в `fuzzyQuery`. Я указывал следующие значения:

```
wildcardQuery.setBoost(10);
fuzzyQuery.setBoost(0.01f);//соотношение 10/0.01 подобрано опытным путем
```